# How to add and remove active class on click - angular way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am doing like this

```
 <div class="tiles" ng-repeat="stat in states" ng-click="select(stat)" ng-class="{active: isActive(stat)}">
    ....
    </div>
```

//controller

```
$scope.select= function(item) {
    $scope.selected = item; 
};

 $scope.isActive = function(item) {
      return $scope.selected === item;

};
```

clicking on tiles it is adding active class and clicking on other tiles removing from first tiles and adding to another tiles.It is working as expected .But what i am trying to achieve is clicking on same tiles again i have to remove active class ,clicking on again i have to add like toggling .But no idea how to achieve this .Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change your code to this:

```
$scope.select= function(item) {
    if (item === $scope.selected) {
        $scope.selected = null;
    } else {
        $scope.selected = item;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Update your select function to set the `selected` property to `null` if it's already selected:

```
$scope.select = function(item) {
    $scope.selected = ($scope.selected === item ? null : item); 
};
```

**JSFiddle Example**

**[http://jsfiddle.net/bATZ5/](http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/bATZ5/)**