# Angular: how to create navigation menu where active class gets toggled on click?

Tags: angularjs

I've created an **AngularJS navigation menu** and I'm trying to **highlight the active menu item** based on **`ng-repeat`**.

So far I have the menu working with `ng-repeat`, but I don't know what to put in the `ng-click` function for the active class to get applied.

Here's what I have:

Here is my **view**:

```
//View (in jade):
ul(ng-controller='MenuCtrl')
    li(ng-repeat='navLink in navLinks', ng-click='select(navLink)', ng-class='{active: navLink.linkhref == path}')
        a(href='{{navLink.linkhref}}') {{navLink.linktext}}
```

And here is my **controller**:

```
//Controller:
...
  controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope,$location) {
    $scope.navLinks = [{
        linkhref: '/',
        linktext: 'View Dashboard',
    }, {
        linkhref: '/rpm',
        linktext: 'View RPMs',
    }, {
        linkhref: '/status',
        linktext: 'View Status',
    }, {
        linkhref: '/database',
        linktext: 'View Database',
    }, {
        linkhref: '/config',
        linktext: 'View Configurations',
    }];

    $scope.path = $location.path();

    $scope.select = function(navLink) {
        //idk what to put here to make the "active" class toggle between nav links
        //I could try this: 
        //remove "active" class from nav links
        //then add "active" class to this link
    };
  })
...
```

Here's a **fiddle** with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bATZ5/1/

So far here is the **behavior**:

- when I go to http://localhost**/status**, the "**View status**" link has the "**active**" class on it. great!
- when I **click another link**, the "**View status**" link ***stays*** "**active**", and the **new link does *not* get the "active" class** added.
- basically **nothing happens when i click**, but **refreshing the page works** (because of the "path == path" thing)

**Resources** that were helpful:

- [ng-class to highlight active menu item based on ng-repeat. AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943217/ng-class-to-highlight-active-menu-item-based-on-ng-repeat-angularjs)
- [How to add and remove active class on click - angular way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474105/how-to-add-and-remove-active-class-on-click-angular-way)
- http://jsfiddle.net/bATZ5/

Comment: The function should update `$scope.path` to `navLink.linkhref` (simply because those are what you compare when assigning the `active` class in your `ng-class`). http://jsfiddle.net/bATZ5/2/ . However, it's worth noting that this simply makes your solution work. It still has flaw inherent in the original solution (e.g. somewhere on the `li` element that is not the link; the route won't change but the active highlight will). You might, instead, want to watch `$routeChangeSuccess`, or something along those lines.

Comment: @DRobinson It worked!! Thank you!! I'll keep workin at it, thank you for the tips! If you make an answer, I'll select it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your list elements, the `ngClick` directive is comparing the scope's `path` value with the navLink element's `linkhref` value. So if you want the item to gain the class, simply set the values:

```
$scope.select = function(navLink) {
    $scope.path = navLink.linkhref;
}
```

While this solves your problem, I believe there's a larger issue with this approach to a menu. Clicking the `li` element outside of the link will cause the item to appear active. Also, navigating with the keyboard (or in any way that doesn't trigger `ngClick`) will not update the menu.

Instead of binding the click, it might be worth exploring a method that watches the route:

```
function updateActiveLink(){
    $scope.path = $location.path();
}
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', updateActiveLink);
```

Or another option that I don't like as much:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ 
    return $location.path();
}, updateActiveLink);
```